# about CORS between mobile application and web application

Tags: android, ios, angularjs

I encountered CORS error that when I `fetch` api from my web application. Oddly, that problem not occurred when I `fetch` that same API with `POSTMAN` and Mobile App (iOs & Android). That's why I'm about to talk my backend/server engineer to open CORS my web app IP address. But I'm concerned that I have no answer to explain him when he ask me why `POSTMAN` & `Mobile App` can be able to call that API even not web app.

> Failed to load http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xx:8082/external/access_token:
>   Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://127.0.0.1:8080' is therefore not allowed
>   access. The response had HTTP status code 500. If an opaque response
>   serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the
>   resource with CORS disabled.

Please let me know how should I explain him.

Comment: CORS is a security measure enforced by your web browser, specifically. POSTMAN does not enforce CORS (it doesn't need to), neither do mobile apps. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CORS is a security measure designed to prevent **web pages** from making requests to domains OTHER THAN THE DOMAIN THE PAGE WAS RECEIVED FROM (unless the server says it's ok).

Postman does not load a web page from one source and make API requests to another source. CORS does not make sense here. The same goes for mobile apps. No webpage loaded from one source and trying to make requests to another source.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing